# How do I list out particular tables from my database in PowerBI?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

How do I list out particular tables from my database in PowerBI as well as their individual information in a dynamic way? 
[This is what I'm trying to do but in here its in the Power Query editor. I want to be able to make this in the dashboard. Is this possible and how?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6rJM.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to see?

Comment: I added a screenshot to the question for an example of what I hope to achieve

Comment: So you want the top table or the bottom table or some combination of them?

Comment: Yea I'd like some combination of them, where In the dashboard, when I select the table on the top, a preview of the table appears as shown in the bottom.